# How can I install the PHP Client for Lob API (apparently using Composer) on a shared server?

Tags: php, github, composer-php, lob

I can't figure this out for the life of me. They recommend using Composer to get their [PHP API Client](https://github.com/lob/lob-php) up and running, but I'm wondering if I *have* to, because it's been a pain in the butt. Here's their installation instructions:

Install Composer
`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

Add Lob.com PHP client as a dependency
`composer require lob/lob-php`

From what I understand, my host (InMotion Hosting/cPanel) does in fact support the Composer installation, but they won't offer help on how to install it. Can somebody break this down for me? Or is there a way to use this PHP API without Composer?

As always, thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you using any kind of framework on the site?

Comment: @khartnett At this point I just downloaded everything from GitHub, uploaded it to my server, and I'm trying to get one of their examples to execute on my server. When I run their examples, they are looking for "vendor/autoload.php", which is a Composer situation if I'm correct.

Comment: That's correct. If you require the "vendor/autoload.php" file, it should make the package classes available in your code

Comment: There 'might' be a way to do this without composer, but honestly I don't think it would be at all easier.

Comment: If you download their source code and use an Autoloader of your own, should be no problem.  Just so happens I have an Autoloader on [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Autoloader) ... lol

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Wow, cool. Do I need to do any editing with something like this or do I just include the file in the PHP?

Comment: You just include it, it's documented on github.  You may have to `registerPath` but that depends on where the autloader is, and where the classes are etc...